# SQL "IS NOT NULL" in SAP HANA SQLScript

Tags: hana, isnull, hana-sql-script

Actually I tried to run a `is null` SQL Statement on a SAP HANA Database using the SAP HANA Studio. This does not work because SQLScript has no `is not null` or `is null` function. My statement looks like:

```
Select *
From MSEG
Where KDAUF is null
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Does anybody know an alternative approach which is practicable using SAP HANA SQLScript? On the internet I found a hint to either use `NULLIF` or `COALESCE`. But I neither know how to use this function nor to adapt it to a working `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULLIF ( expression , expression )
Returns the same type as the first expression.

NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression
WHERE IFNULL(KDAUF , comparison value) I never use this one

The other is coalesce where if the first vaLue is null, the second VALUE is returned:

WHERE VALUEa = COALESCE(KDAUF,valuea)

here, if kdaUf Is null, coalesce will will return valuea, the default if the first value is null. Since valuea = valuea, the where clause will be true, which is just another way of validating that KDAUF IS NULL

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can not understand your `COALESCE` solution. So maybe, for a better understanding, you can implement the `COALESCE` solution using my little code example: `Select *
From MSEG
Where KDAUF is null`

Comment: SELECT * FROM MSEG WHERE 1 = COALESCE(KDAUF,1).         .....     If Kdauf is NULL, COALESCE will go to the next option, 1, 1=1, and the WHERE clause will return TRUE.  If KDAUF is NOT null, COALesce will return the value of kduaf (I'm assuming it will never be 1), kduaf will not be equal to 1, and the where clause will fail.  A bit counter-intuitive, but very useful.

Comment: Note - any value can be used for the where initial value and the coalesce function's second variable, as long as they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it this way

```
Select * from MSEG Where KDAUF **NE** ''
```